# Vue.js Switch statement not assigning variable

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I have this switch statement that isn't working. For some reason its not assigning a new value to `percentDiscount` when it runs. I'm not sure why?

```
  figureOutPercentDiscount(numberOfProducts) {
    let percentDiscount = 1
    switch(numberOfProducts) {
      case numberOfProducts <= 5:
        percentDiscount = 0
        break;
      case numberOfProducts > 5 && numberOfProducts < 1000:
        percentDiscount = 1
        break;
      case numberOfProducts >= 1000 && numberOfProducts >= 2000:
        percentDiscount = .7
        break;
    }
    return percentDiscount
  }
```

And when I call it like this:

`let percentDiscount = this.figureOutPercentDiscount(products)`

It always returns 1 regardless of the number fed into the method.

EDIT:
Interestingly the switch statement isn't even being entered.. I put in some logging, and none of the logs are getting hit.

Comment: What does this log console.log(products)? maybe you need products.length

Comment: `numberOfProducts >= 1000 && numberOfProducts >= 2000` If it is more than 2000 for sure it will be more than 1000, I think you mean `numberOfProducts >= 1000 && numberOfProducts <= 2000`

Comment: @XMehdi01 well I made sure it was a number, and it is.. so its just being fed a number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cases in a switch statement should be values that you want to match against, not conditions. Whatever you pass in will be compared to the value (or condition converted to a value) in the case block.

The condition you are using will be converted to a value (boolean),  which is compared against whatever is passed in (numberOfProducts). So in the first case block, it is saying "if (condition) = numberOfProducts, then go into this block". But because conditions are always evaluated to a boolean (true or false), and numberOfProducts is an integer and not a boolean, it won't match. If you want to use conditions, you could compare them against 'true' like this:

```
figureOutPercentDiscount(numberOfProducts) {
  let percentDiscount = 1;
  switch(true) {
    case numberOfProducts <= 5:
      percentDiscount = 0;
      break;
    case numberOfProducts > 5 && numberOfProducts < 1000:
      percentDiscount = 1;
      break;
    case numberOfProducts >= 1000 && numberOfProducts < 2000:
      percentDiscount = .7;
      break;
  }
  return percentDiscount;
}
```

This is now saying "if (condition) = true, then enter this block".
Hope this helps!

Comment: Also, it will only match with one of them, and that will be whichever one matches first. So if it doesn't match with the first one it will definitely be over 5, and same for 1,000. So in your last two conditions you can remove the first half of each "numberOfProducts > 5 && " and "numberOfProducts >= 1000 && ".